Possible cause of electric oven failure?
I'm not sure what has failed in my electric oven. I had it warming up to temperature to cook a meal. I heard a loud pop and it's now completely dead. The hob which is also connected up to the same isolator switch is now dead.
I'm not sure if the socket adjacent to the isolator is also off the same supply as the kettle which wasn't in use at the time is also dead. I'll move the kettle to another socket later and see if it still works.
I won't be able to check the MCB for the oven circuit until the morning as the consumer unit is outside of my flat.
To make sure it's safe I've switched the isolator into the off position.
What was the most likely source of the loud pop that I heard (and is likely the cause of the failure)?
Once I know what has likely failed I can google the probably cost of the repair and decide if it'll be cheaper to just buy a new oven.

If you open the oven do you see a white powdery residue near the heating element?  If there is, the likely cause is a failed heating element which shorted to the oven floor tripping the circuit breaker.  Anything beyond that will require more advanced trouble shooting skills.

"isolator switch" -- do you mean circuit breaker?

@keshlam it's a double-pole switch next to the oven & hob

Ah. Not something common in the US, at least in my experience.

In the UK you have a double-pole isolator by the oven and then in the consumer unit you have a MCB (probably will be an RCBO in a more recent install). It's the isolator next to the oven I turned off. The MCB in the consumer unit has been turned back on.

I heard a loud pop
indicates there was a major short circuit.
probably caused by melted insulation between the wires somewhere,
your circuit breaker must have triggered.
googling for spare parts will not help, only a professional can fix that

Think the circuit breaker has tripped, as the double socket next to the oven isolator switch must be off of the same breaker. The kettle is normally plugged into the socket but wasn't in use at the time. I'll probably get an electrician in to physically disconnect the oven, so at least then I'll be able to use the hob again.

This is impossible to answer without opening up the appliance and examining what failed. It could be that a connector overheated and caused insulation to melt. It could be that a thermocouple has failed. It could be that the control panel has failed. The only way to find out is to examine it, apply a multimeter, and find the place where it isn't doing what it should be.
Trying to guess is probably an exercise in frustrating replacement of parts that did not need to be replaced.
If you want to repair it yourself, you really have to learn how to diagnose it first. We can't do that remotely for you.
The alternative is hire somebody who does know what they're doing.

It sounds like it's just going to be far easier to just get a new oven, as the failed one is about 10-years-old

One possible cause is that a heating element has failed, burst, and the inner heating wire has struck/welded to the sheath. This can pass enough current to trip the breaker.
Testing or physical inspection of the individual elements usually makes it fairly clear that it has failed. Most elements can be easily unclipped and unplugged.

Not something I have ever heard of happening, but I'll take your word for it that it's possible. And yes, that's an easy replacement if it is the cause.

I've seen a number of heating elements explode, in ovens and other applications. It's rare for them to trip the breaker but not impossible.

I've gone for a new oven. The brand of the old one seems to have gone from the sorts of shop that sell ovens. The old one was a "budget brand"

The parts are usually pretty interchangeable and available (no/very few appliance brands make their own elements), but fair enough.
